# How can I require a generic parameter to be an enum that implements an interface?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm not 100% convinced that this is a good idea, but I bumped into some code today that's currently implemented as:

```
class MyWidget <T extends Enum<T> > {
  MyWidget(Map<T, Integer> valueMap) {
    mValueMap = valueMap;
  }

  Map<T, Integer> mValueMap;
}
```

where `MyWidget` then offers methods that use `mValueMap` to convert the passed-in `Enum` to/from an `Integer`.

What I was considering doing was trying to refactor this, so that I'd declare my enumeration:

```
interface MyInterface {
  public Integer getValue();
}

enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
  foo, bar;
  public Integer getValue() {
    return ordinal();
  }
}
```

And I'd then be able to rewrite `MyWidget` into something that looked vaguely like this:

```
public class MyWidget<T extends Enum<T> extends MyInterface> {
  ...
}
```

and would then be able to call the `getValue()` method from `MyInterface` on `T`-type objects within `MyWidget`.  The problem, of course, is that "`<T extends Enum<T> extends MyInterface>`" isn't valid syntax.  Is there any way to pull this off?

I don't want to just have `MyWidget<T extends MyInterface>`, because it's also important that T be an enumeration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use an '`&`' instead:

```
public class MyWidget<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> {
    ...
}
```

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9) calls this an "intersection type", but I can find no mention of it in the Java tutorials. I'll just say that it does exactly what you were wishing that "`extends`" would do.

Also, I should mention that you can have as many types as you want in the intersection type. So if you wanted, you could do:

```
public class MyWidget<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface & Serializable & Cloneable> {
    ...
}
```

*[Note: this code sample should not be construed as an endorsement of the `Cloneable` interface; it was merely handy at the time.]*

Comment: The & syntax is neat, but I find that using it usually turns into a code smell, and is an indication that something is not quite right with your model.

Comment: I tend to agree (I think I've used it maybe once or twice, if that). But in the case of enums implementing an interface, I think it is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Your post somehow made me realize, that what I really needed was along the lines of ... `doSomething(Enum<? extends SomeInterface>)`

Comment: @skaffmann if you'd find time to share your experience WRT related **code smells**, I'd really appreciate

Comment: +10  Never would have figured this out on my own.  The only way to handle enums with interfaces.

Comment: It is the first time I have to use this "&" operator and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JSR 203 (new new IO) stuff for JDK 7 is making a lot of use of enums that implement interfaces (for example: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html) to allow them some wiggle room in the future for future additional sets of enum options.  So that is a feasible approach and obviously one that was chosen after a lot of thought in one large Sun project.

Comment: Neat.  Hopefully java 7 will appear before my beard goes grey.

Comment: From writing a small amount of code that uses this stuff, my impression is that it's a little weird.  Can't say I've seen it anywhere else. 

Something with a 7 in the name will release in 2010 I'm pretty sure.  Whether it will be "Java 7" as endorsed by the JCP, I don't know.  Only Oracle can answer that now...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html