# Java generic Types for method signature on enums implementing

Tags: java, enums, interface

I basically want to have an `enum` with specific methods, e.g.

```
public interface PropertyTypeMethods {
    public int getTypeId();

    public void setTypeId(Integer typeId);
}
```

and something like

```
public enum BasePropertyTypes implements PropertyTypeMethods {

ONE, TWO;

private int typeId;

@Override
public int getTypeId() {
    return typeId;
}

@Override
public void setTypeId(Integer typeId) {
    this.typeId = typeId;
}

}
```

as well as an extended version of this enum, e.g.

```
public enum ExtendedPropertyTypes implements PropertyTypeMethods {
HUNDRED, THOUSEND; 
// same as above
}
```

which would result in `ONE.setTypeId(1)` ==> `ONE.getTypeId()==1 //true`. That is the basic concept. But now I want to call a generic method like e.g.

```
private <E extends Enum<E> & PropertyTypeMethods> void initEnum(Enum<E> curType) {
   // the below approach does not work :-/
   curType.setTypeId(1); // or any other reasonable value....
```

But somehow I cannot figure out what the *correct* method signature would be. Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070703/how-can-i-require-a-generic-parameter-to-be-an-enum-that-implements-an-interface) I figured at least some part of the puzzle -
 but still don't get it for the method signature. Still it remains unclear how to specify `curType` properly in the signature to execute an appropriate call.

Comment: Why `<E extends Enum<E> & PropertyTypeMethodes>`? To set the type, `<E extends PropertyTypeMethods>` is enough.

Comment: Enums are supposed to be constant. If you want a mutable "enum", make it a plain old class.

Comment: Just create a class, give it a `private` or `protected` constructor and add constant instances. Voila, it's basically an mutable and extendable enum. You may also add a `static` method to provide all available instances of that class like `values()` on enums.

Comment: Like Andy said, enum values should be constants.  I think what you really want is an [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

Comment: Well I need to review the other suggestion .... About the _Why?_ The main problem is this enum is already cluttered all over the code. And now there is a breaking change to set the ids manually - instead of hard coded (as it was). Therefore the request... I would love to have it differently - from the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work :

```
private <E extends Enum<E> & PropertyTypeMethods> void initEnum(E curType) {
  curType.setTypeId(1);
}
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to make mutable `Enum`s (they're meant to be labels over constant values, not state-carrying singletons). Furthermore, you shouldn' write methods that require an `Enum` parameter when all they should care about is its interface :

```
// This will be easier to work with down the road
private void initEnum(PropertyTypeMethods curType) {
  curType.setTypeId(1);
}
```

Comment: Upvote for pointing out the pointlessness of the whole thing ;-)

Comment: Thx the hint with the signature solved this issue. I don't see my situation as ideal - nevertheless it works with the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct signature would simply be

```
private void initEnum(PropertyTypeMethods onject) {
    object.setTypeId(1);
}
```

But as Andy Turner mentioned, enums are expected to be immutable, i.e. only final immutable field. Therefore, enums also have a constructor [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

If you have more complex enums, it is a common way to implement them as follows

```
public enum BasePropertyTypes implements PropertyTypeMethods {
   ONE (new PropertyTypeMethods() {
          @Override
          public int getTypeId() {
              return 1;
          }
     });

    private final PropertyTypeMethods m;

    BasePropertyTypes(PropertyTypeMethods m) {
       this.m = m;
    }

   @Override
   public int getTypeId()
   {
      return this.m.getTypeId();
   }
}
```

But from your example, I would suggest to review your actual issue. Propably enums are not the proper way at all.

Comment: Yeah, I need to review - but anyway this enum is used all over the code - and a breaking change reg. ID needs some other measures - which are not as intended at the very beginning.... See as well my other comment..